# Installing an older version of an emacs package

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I recently upgraded Emacs Cider through MELPA and it seems to have a bug on my machine. I don't need the bleeding edge builds and am happy to go back to an older build until they fix the [issue](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/issues/443). However I'm not sure how to install an older version of a package that exists in the package list.

I am looking to either:

1. Install an older version of Cider through the native Emacs package manager
2. Install an older version of Cider from source

Edit: this was closed as a duplicate of [Is it possible to downgrade packages installed with ELPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591061/is-it-possible-to-downgrade-packages-installed-with-elpa), however that one didn't have an answer, so I re-asked the question.

Comment: This is IMO one of ELPA's biggest weaknesses. It is exceedingly difficult to install old versions of things.

Comment: To repeat my comment from http://stackoverflow.com/q/21591061/324105: "This is (one of the reasons) why I keep my entire Emacs configuration under version control. If I upgrade a library and it breaks things, I simply revert it. I recommend doing likewise."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following

1) Uninstall `cider` from emacs' native package manager. (Do `M-x list-packages` mark the cider package using `d` and then hit `x` to delete the package)

2) Download the last version which worked for you from cider's [releases page](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/releases)

3) Follow the manual installation instructions given [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#manual)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This fixed my problems as well.  BTW, manual installation instructions are currently [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/wiki/Installation#manual).

Comment: maunal installation link is broken.